# vector Declaration in c++

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

I am trying to write a code using c++  for the first time and I found this line:

```
vector<vector<vector<double> > > h(hist1, vector<vector<double> >(hist2, vector<double>(nb_bins, 0.0)));
```

I don't understand what does it means, can you help me guys? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let's unpack it!

```
vector<vector<vector<double> > >
  h(hist1,
    vector<vector<double> > (hist2,
                             vector<double> (nb_bins, 0.0) ) );
```

This is a declaration of a variable of type `vector<vector<vector<double> > >` called `h`.  `h` is initialized by calling its constructor, passing in as a first parameter `hist1`, and as its second parameter a temporary object of type `vector<vector<double> >`.  This temporary object is in turn initialized by calling its constructor, passing in `hist2` as its first parameter and a temporary `vector<double>` as its second parameter.  This second temporary is then initialized by calling its constructor, passing in `nb_bins` as its first parameter and `0.0` as its second.

The result is that this ends up acting as a three-dimensional array of dimension `hist1` × `hist2` × `nb_bins`, where each value is initialized to 0.0.

That said, if you want to use a 3D array, look into the Boost.MultiArray package, which gives a *much* cleaner way to do this.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's a vector of vector of vector of double, something like a tridimensional array of double. See here : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/